# how to Set DateFormat for date field in phonegap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am developing Phonegap application.
In that i have date field for that i have to change DateFormat from (2015-03-16 to 16-Mar-2015). So please tell me how to solve this one.I am using Jquerymobile

Comment: Do you mean in JavaScript? What have you tried? Some code would be helpful too

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to format javascript date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-javascript-date)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

var m_names = new Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", 
"Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sept", 
"Oct", "Nov", "Dec");

var d = new Date();
var curr_date = d.getDate();
var curr_month = d.getMonth();
var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
document.write(curr_date + "-" + m_names[curr_month] 
+ "-" + curr_year);

//-->
</script>
```

Comment: Hi all.I am using jquerymobile date field on selecting Date from datepicker i need to change the date format as above.

Comment: I have to set date format for datepicker i am uisng jquerymobile